# WSUS WUServer Registry Key

Tags: wsus, windows-server-2019, automatic-updates

I am having a hard time figuring this out. I started up a WSUS in our environment and everything was working fine up until a month ago. We are about 200 computers company wide and I had 10-15 at most checking in with the server. I noticed that all the computers that are no longer checking in have the WUServer string in the registry empty. If I do gpupdate /force it will populate again but will disappear maybe 30 minutes later. What am I missing. I have run RSOP.msc to confirm no other GPO could be fighting with it. Anyone else have issues with this?

Comment: Is **WUStatusServer** configured?

Comment: It is. It was installing updates on the machines for a few months and then just randomly stopped and nothing in the environment changed. The only thing I noticed is that in the registry WUServer and WUStatusServer keep clearing the values. I can run gpupdate /force and then the correct info shows up there but then disappears in 30 minutes.

Comment: Are you using any third party systems management or patch management tools?

Comment: We are using NinjaRMM for system management.

Comment: My guess is that Ninja is resetting these Registry keys. An easy way to confirm this would be to remove the Ninja agent on one machine and see if that resolves the issue. Secondarily, if you are using Ninja for Windows Updates management then you don't need to use WSUS... or vice versa. Pick one Windows Updates mechanism and stop using the other one.

Comment: I want to thank you for helping me brainstorm this issue! I don’t know why I never thought of NinjaRMM taking over. I have disabled it because I don’t like how it manages updates.

Comment: Glad to help...